# playbook need to check java version and if the java version below 1.8* version then playbook install java 1.8*

Tags: java, ansible, version

i wrote the below code but not succeed to install java 1.8 version in target server. getting error while executing playbook

```
---
- hosts: server
  name: Fetch Java version
  shell: java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
  register: java_version
- name: install java 1.8.* version
  yum: name={{item}} state=latest
  with_items:
    - java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
  when: java_version != 1.8.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
---
hosts: server_name
tasks:
  - name: install java        
    yum:
      name: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
      state: present
```

Ansible state will take care if the above version is present or not

Note:- Kindly use proper formatting in the question